# Who is better here? [hard]

Tags: online-chess

Who is better in this position? White or black? Hard one!
[image]

Comment: Is this position something you're wondering about the correct evaluation of, or do you know the correct evaluation already, posting this as sort of a brain teaser for the community? The question in this post seems to indicate that you want to know who is better and why, whereas the comment "Hard one!" seems to indicate that this is a puzzle to which you already know the solution. Without looking very deeply I'd say that black is clearly winning here after Bxf7 based on simply being a piece up for very little compensation.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an interesting position. I am assuming it is black to move because the highlighted knight move should be the last one, and also because otherwise black would lose their queen for no good reason.

It seems that **white manages to get some compensation by forcing black to exchange their queen for a rook**. However, the evaluation still favors black by a bit less than -2. Anyway, the ending looks very difficult to convert.

[This](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/r2q2k1/pp3Npp/1np1b3/2Q5/3r4/2N5/PP4PP/4RRK1_b_KQkq_-) analysis is according to Stockfish 9 at depth 22:

```
[FEN "r2q2k1/pp3Npp/1np1b3/2Q5/3r4/2N5/PP4PP/4RRK1 b Qq - 0 1"]
[Startply "0"]

1... Bxf7 2. Re7 Bc4 3. Qg5 g6 4. Qe5 Qxe7 5. Qxe7 Rd7 6. Qe1 Bxf1 7. Kxf1 Nd5
```

Comment: I essentially agree with your conclusions, and I think that this answer is far better than my comment since the variation you presented is very important to the final evaluation. What is clear in the final position is that black is at the very least much better since he's managed to consolidate a nontrivial material advantage successfully, and it will be exceedingly difficult for white to find a good practical defense if there exists one; the pair of rooks tends to be stronger than the queen once they start coordinating well, and that seems imminent in the final position.